# add a if condition to rails delete function and pass a alert message to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show alert message in view when the given condition is failed. My code is ....

```
  def delete
     @items = PrdItem.find(params[:id])
     @item_odr=OdrOrderLine.where(prd_item_id: @items.id).pluck(:id)

     if @item_odr!=null
        @items.destroy
        @vendor_id  = UsrContactVendor.find_by_usr_contact_id(current_usr_contact.id).usr_vendor_property_id
        redirect_to usr_vendor_property_path(@vendor_id)
     else
         flash[:notice] = "Cannot be deleted"
         @vendor_id  = UsrContactVendor.find_by_usr_contact_id(current_usr_contact.id).usr_vendor_property_id
         redirect_to usr_vendor_property_path(@vendor_id)
```

Comment: What condition? What have you tried so far? What's not working?

Comment: it doesnt  show the alert message in view

Comment: Are you taking about the `flash[:notice]`? This is not the same thing as an "alert message", which is why I presumed not. Where is your view code? You need to provide a [mcve] of the problem; you have not given us enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of `OdrOrderLine.where(prd_item_id: @items.id).pluck(:id)` will always make the condition `@item_odr!=null` return true.

First, it is important to note that `null` isn't a Ruby keyword, you probably want to use `nil` instead. This doesn't raise an error because there is no local variable `null` defined and therefore `null` simply returns `nil`. But this line might confuse to other developers.

Second, if there is no matching record in the database then `OdrOrderLine.where(prd_item_id: @items.id).pluck(:id)` will return an empty array. Therefore you will never be able to get into the `else` branch.

Perhaps something like this is more readable:

```
def delete
  @item = PrdItem.find(params[:id])

  if OdrOrderLine.where(prd_item_id: @item.id).any?
    flash[:notice] = "Cannot be deleted"
    # ...

  else
    @item.destroy
    # ...
```

Btw I renamed the `@items` variable to `@item` because `find` returns only one record.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this at the start of a form, this can generate error messages for you and allow you to keep your controller skinnier.

```
<% if @item.errors.any? %>
      <h3><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h3>
      <ul>
        <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li>
          <%= message %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
```